# Float element background color

Tags: css, css-float

Why the `.box` has white background instead of yellow as `.wrapper` has yellow background however it's text does have green color font as `.wrapper` has green color font.

Link -- https://codepen.io/ravenkhan03/pen/mzdvKM

```css
body {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font: .9em/1.2 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif
}

.wrapper {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 10px;
  color: green;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.box {
  float: left;
  margin: 15px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>Simple float example</h1>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">Float</div>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla luctus aliquam dolor, eu lacinia lorem placerat vulputate. </p>
</div>
<p style="clear:left">Duis felis orci, pulvinar id metus ut, rutrum luctus orci. Cras porttitor imperdiet nunc, at ultricies tellus laoreet sit amet. Sed auctor cursus massa at porta. Integer ligula ipsum, tristique sit amet orci vel, viverra egestas ligula. Curabitur vehicula
  tellus neque, ac ornare ex malesuada et. In vitae convallis lacus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Suspendisse ac imperdiet turpis. Aenean finibus sollicitudin eros pharetra congue. Duis ornare egestas augue ut luctus. Proin blandit quam nec lacus varius commodo
  et a urna. Ut id ornare felis, eget fermentum sapien.</p>

<p>Nam vulputate diam nec tempor bibendum. Donec luctus augue eget malesuada ultrices. Phasellus turpis est, posuere sit amet dapibus ut, facilisis sed est. Nam id risus quis ante semper consectetur eget aliquam lorem. Vivamus tristique elit dolor, sed pretium
  metus suscipit vel. Mauris ultricies lectus sed lobortis finibus. Vivamus eu urna eget velit cursus viverra quis vestibulum sem. Aliquam tincidunt eget purus in interdum. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus
  mus.</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the [background-color property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color) isn't inherited and the default value is transparent (the [color property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color) however, is inherited).

Comment: Addition, in order to inherit the color use, in the box class background-color:inherit; . It will inherit from parent element.

Comment: Downvoter care to comment as to how this is incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font: .9em/1.2 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   background-color: yellow;
}
.wrapper {
  padding: 10px;
  color: green;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.box {
  float: left;
  margin: 15px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>Simple float example</h1>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">Float</div>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla luctus aliquam dolor, eu lacinia lorem placerat vulputate. </p>
</div>
<p style="clear:left">Duis felis orci, pulvinar id metus ut, rutrum luctus orci. Cras porttitor imperdiet nunc, at ultricies tellus laoreet sit amet. Sed auctor cursus massa at porta. Integer ligula ipsum, tristique sit amet orci vel, viverra egestas ligula. Curabitur vehicula
  tellus neque, ac ornare ex malesuada et. In vitae convallis lacus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Suspendisse ac imperdiet turpis. Aenean finibus sollicitudin eros pharetra congue. Duis ornare egestas augue ut luctus. Proin blandit quam nec lacus varius commodo
  et a urna. Ut id ornare felis, eget fermentum sapien.</p>

<p>Nam vulputate diam nec tempor bibendum. Donec luctus augue eget malesuada ultrices. Phasellus turpis est, posuere sit amet dapibus ut, facilisis sed est. Nam id risus quis ante semper consectetur eget aliquam lorem. Vivamus tristique elit dolor, sed pretium
  metus suscipit vel. Mauris ultricies lectus sed lobortis finibus. Vivamus eu urna eget velit cursus viverra quis vestibulum sem. Aliquam tincidunt eget purus in interdum. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus
  mus.</p>
```

Comment: Hi, this is not what I was expecting in the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font: .9em/1.2 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 10px;
  color: green;
  border:1px solid red;
}
 .box {
  margin: 15px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 1em;
  border:1px solid black;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:inherit;
}
```

```html
<h1>Simple float example</h1>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">Float</div>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla luctus aliquam dolor, eu lacinia lorem placerat vulputate. </p>
</div>        
<p style="clear:left">Duis felis orci, pulvinar id metus ut, rutrum luctus orci. Cras porttitor imperdiet nunc, at ultricies tellus laoreet sit amet. Sed auctor cursus massa at porta. Integer ligula ipsum, tristique sit amet orci vel, viverra egestas ligula. Curabitur vehicula tellus neque, ac ornare ex malesuada et. In vitae convallis lacus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Suspendisse ac imperdiet turpis. Aenean finibus sollicitudin eros pharetra congue. Duis ornare egestas augue ut luctus. Proin blandit quam nec lacus varius commodo et a urna. Ut id ornare felis, eget fermentum sapien.</p>
        
<p>Nam vulputate diam nec tempor bibendum. Donec luctus augue eget malesuada ultrices. Phasellus turpis est, posuere sit amet dapibus ut, facilisis sed est. Nam id risus quis ante semper consectetur eget aliquam lorem. Vivamus tristique elit dolor, sed pretium metus suscipit vel. Mauris ultricies lectus sed lobortis finibus. Vivamus eu urna eget velit cursus viverra quis vestibulum sem. Aliquam tincidunt eget purus in interdum. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>
```

Comment: as you want only wrapper class to background yellow color